# CSS/HTML Page won't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, dreamweaver

My CSS code is as follows:

```
    body {
        background-image: url(images/bg.png);
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
    }
```

The background image is obviously larger than a standard webpage, but it still won't let me scroll down.

[A side note - I also cannot scroll down in the design view: http://www.meikledesign.co.uk/host/example.jpg]

Comment: you've sent the image as background, it only displays the part that is visible in the body. you want full display of the background? if so, take a look at this [link](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 2):

Give the body a finite height for testing purposes.

```
body {
   height: 2000px;
}
```

Backgrounds do not artificially increase the body of an html page (defined, by default, as 100%, 100% of browser window) if I remember correctly.

Comment: Top one. The background fits the body, not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

Change the body min-height to the bg.png height, not too pretty solution, but works

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve responsive background, then check this [perfect-full-page-background-image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

you can achieve that with css3, like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

but that way it wont work in all browsers.
Check the link i provided for crossbrowser solution.

And about scrolling, you can do that as other members said earlier, by adding `min-height` to the body.